# Delegate between Container View and ViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, uicontainerview, swift-protocols

I asked that [question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298760/delegate-using-container-view-in-swift/), and I got the solution to what he sought. Now, I need to amplify my question. **Using delegates, how can I create a Delegate to the ViewController send data to the ContainerView and ContainerView send data to the ViewController**?

Comment: So in short you want to pass data between two classes?

Comment: Yes, but my big problem is to use the Container View in a ViewController.

Comment: So, sorry being a bit slow here, is the view controller you're talking about embedded in the container view, or is the container view in the view controller?

Comment: This link explain the storyboard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298760/delegate-using-container-view-in-swift/

Comment: Right, so you've got one view controller embedded in another and you want to pass data between them

Comment: Yes. Imagine that one needs to "talk" to each other.

Comment: I don't know if this would work for you, but what I've always done is kept a superView variable in my embedded ViewController class, and in the prepareForSegue function of the superview controller, set that variable to self, and kept a record of the embedded VC

Comment: I tried using segues. ContainerView worked for the ViewController. But ViewController to ContainerView does not.

Comment: Hang on, let me post an answer so I can properly format what I'm suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this is entirely what you're looking for, but what I've always done in this situation is kept a record of each view controller inside the other's class.

For example if your container view has the embed segue with identifier `"Embed Segue"` then your classes might look like:

Superview Class

```
Class ViewControllerOne: UIViewController {
var data = "This is my data I may want to change"
var subView: ViewControllerTwo?

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Embed Segue" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerTwo
            destinationVC.superView = self
            self.subView = destinationVC
        }
    }
}
```

Embedded Class

```
Class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {
    var data = "This is the other view controller's copy of that data"
    var superView: ViewControllerOne?
}
```

Then you can pass data between these View Controllers simply by referencing `self.subView.data` and `self.superView.data` respectively.

**Edit:** For ViewControllerTwo to pass data back to ViewControllerOne, it would then simply have to reference `self.superView.data`.  e.g:

```
Class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {
    var data = "This is the other view controller's copy of that data"
    var superView: ViewControllerOne?

    func passDataBack() {
        self.superView.data = self.data
    }
}
```

This would then update the data variable in the first view controller.

Comment: This is the piece of code that I already have.I must have this code and more the reverse that. The ViewControllerTwo pass data to ViewControllerOne.

Comment: @James I've edited my answer to make it clearer what's happening to pass data back up the chain